Add eventListener on React Component
I want to set an event on Header when an action happened on {children}, how can i do this
function Basic({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default Basic;

I have tried with document event but it didn't work
{chidren} is an over flow y component and when I scroll on it, I expect event will dispatch to Header

Create a state at the top level and pass it to children and listen for state change.
// Header.jsx

import { useEffect } from "react"

function Header({ event }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (event) {
            // Set Event
            console.log("Event Set")
        } else {
            console.log("Event Removed")
        }
    }, [event])
    return <div>Header</div>
}
export default Header


// Basic.jsx

import Header from "./Header"

function Basic({ children, event }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Header event={event} />
            {children}
        </>
    )
}

export default Basic


// MainContainer.jsx

import { useState } from "react"
import Basic from "./Basic"

function Container() {
    const [event, setEvent] = useState(false)
    const handleClick = () => {
        setEvent(!event)
    }
    
    return (
        <Basic event={event}>
            <p>Click on the button</p>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
        </Basic>
    )
}
export default Container



But children of Basic is another component in Route too, how can i pass event data from this children to other component

Learn about props and children.

Use React.cloneElement to send data from callback to prop
  function Basic({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <Header data={data} />
      {React.cloneElement(children, { sendData: setData })}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

